# Recursively copy only certain directories that match patterns listed in a file

Tags: terminal, find, regular-expression, rsync

I have a directory with the following structure:

```
-- 201893208
   └── 8Z12
          └── ko_8Z12_Full
          └── wp_we_8Z12_FullDAT
          └── 8Z12_DATFull
   └── P011
          └── P011_Full
          └── 8Z12_FullDAT
          └── P011_DATFull
   └── 9FZA
          └── kl_wt-we-w_kl9-9FZA_Full
          └── ffd-9FZA_FullDAT
          └── 8fdZ12232_9FZA_DATFull
-- 903240920
   └── P0fsa
          └── P0fsa_Full
          └── P0fsa_FullDAT
          └── P0fsa_DATFull
   └── Paaaf
          └── we-Paaaf_ww_fl_Full
          └── Paaaf_FullDAT
          └── Paaaf_DATFull
   └── 9FZATYYY
          └── 9FZATYYY_Full
          └── 9FZATYYY_FullDAT
-- wt0340291
   └── OPF1121
          └── OPF1121_Full
          └── 8Z12_DATFull
   └── KLOFJ9
          └── lop_KLOFJ9_ffj_Full
          └── powt_KLOFJ9_DATFull
   └── LP02323
          └── wr_we_LP02323_Full
          └── wr_we_LP02323_FullDAT
```

There are thousands of files in each and every folder listed above. And then there are also many subdirectories inside each. For example `8Z12` does not contain only the three folders listed above, but it also contains thousands of files.

I **ONLY** want to copy directories which have `_Full` at the end of their name (**DATFull** directories **should NOT be copied**) **AND also** contain the patterns in the list below

```
LP02323
KLOFJ9
Paaaf
9FZA
```

In other words, the directories that contain a string from the list above **AND** `Full` in their name (but NOT DAT) should be copied.

Therefore in the example above, only the following directories (and all of their contents and sub-directories) should be copied:

```
wr_we_LP02323_Full
lop_KLOFJ9_ffj_Full
we-Paaaf_ww_fl_Full
kl_wt-we-w_kl9-9FZA_Full
```

To my understanding, `rsync` does not support regex, therefore this has to be done with `find` first of all (correct me if I am wrong). But how can I do this in a way to ensure all of the directories and sub-directories are checked and all of the relevant folders are copied even if they are buried very deep in several sub-directories (note that the above example was a simplified structure of my original folder).

So there are two questions:

- How can I provide the list of patterns to `find`?
- How can I pipe the result of `find` to `rsync`?

So far this only comes to my mind to match `Full`:

`find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/.*[^DAT]Full$"`

But how can I add the list of IDs to this `find` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a file of strings that need to be present in the directory names, a shell loop over these, and `rsync` (assuming we want to copy from the directory in the variable `$source` and to the directory in the variable `$target`):

```
while IFS= read -r string; do
    rsync --archive --exclude='*DAT*/' --include='*/' --include="*$string*_Full/***" --exclude='*' \
        --prune-empty-dirs "$source"/ "$target"
done <strings.txt
```

What the options to `rsync` does (the first hit on any of the exclusion/inclusion patters matters):

- `--archive`: Copies ownership, permissions, timestamps etc.
- `--exclude='*DAT*/'`: Exclude any directory with `DAT` in its name.
- `--include='*/'`: Consider all directories (except for the ones excluded by the previous pattern).  This is needed for `rsync` to reach the actual directories that you are interested in.
- `--include="*$string*_Full/***"`: Consider all directories matching the given pattern *and* everything below that directory. If `$string` is `parrot`, this would be `--include="*parrot*_Full/***"`.
- `--exclude='*'`: Don't consider anything not already explicitly included.
- `--prune-empty-dirs`: Don't transfer directories that doesn't have anything explicitly included in them.

If you want to see how `rsync` evaluates the patterns when you run it, add `-vv` to the `rsync` command line.

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
|-- from
|   `-- a
|       `-- b
|           |-- c_A_DATFull
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_A_DAT_Full
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_A_Full
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_B_DATFull
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_B_DAT_Full
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_B_Full
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_C_DATFull
|           |   `-- file
|           |-- c_C_DAT_Full
|           |   `-- file
|           `-- c_C_Full
|               `-- file
`-- strings.txt

12 directories, 10 files

$ cat strings.txt
A
B

$ source=from
$ target=to
```

(running the loop here)

```
$ tree
.
|-- from
[...]
`-- to
    `-- a
        `-- b
            |-- c_A_Full
            |   `-- file
            `-- c_B_Full
                `-- file

17 directories, 12 files
```

With a single invocation of `rsync`:

```
set -- --exclude='*DAT*/' --include='*/'
while IFS= read -r string; do
    set -- "$@" --include="*$string*_Full/***"
done <strings.txt
set -- "$@" --exclude='*'

rsync --archive "$@" --prune-empty-dirs "$source"/ "$target"
```

---

A `find` solution:

```
set --
while IFS= read -r string; do
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*$string*_Full"
done <strings.txt
shift

# "$@" would now be something like
#    -name *LP02323*_Full -o -name *Paaaf*_Full -o -name ...etc

find "$source" -type d '(' "$@" ')' ! -name '*DAT*' -exec sh -c '
    source=$1; target=$2; shift 2
    for pathname do
        mkdir -p "$target/${pathname#$source}"
        rsync --archive "$pathname"/ "$target/${pathname#$source}"
    done' sh "$source" "$target" {} +
```

This would use `find` to generate a list of the subdirectories that you would like to copy.  These are given to a small inline script that loops over them.

In each iteration of the loop, the corresponding directory on the target is created (this assumes local copy), and the directory is copied using `rsync`.

Never ever use `find` to *pipe* pathnames to some other command unless you can arrange for the pathnames to be safely delimited.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I only have to ask a question to satisfy a suspicion, because of what I read in another thread (i.e. `rsync doesn't speak regex`; https://superuser.com/questions/536561/). Does `--include="*$string*_Full/***"` match the `$string` that happens anywhere before `_Full` and will `DAT` truly never be matched? I suspect that with the current pattern, something like `wr_DAT_we_LP02323_Full` will be actually copied.

Comment: @benett `rsync` does not do regular expressions, but filename globbing patterns (with some extentions, such as `***`).  You are rigt that that directory _would_ be copied.  I thought `DAT` always occurred as `DATFull` at the end. This is easily fixed. I will update very soon.

Comment: @benett Fixed now.

Comment: @benett Sorry, I got the ordering of the inclusion/exclusion patterns wrong. Sorted now.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. By the way, do the strings in `strings.txt` have to be separated by line breaks (i.e. `\n`)?

Comment: @benett One string per line, yes. I'll make a small adjustment to the `read` calls to be able to read the newline delimited strings safely.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for the naive request, but I do not understand how to use the last approach (the one with `find`). Would you care to give an example of how and where I should provide my source and target directories? Supposing `source` is `user@vm:/home/data/` and `target` is `/mnt/d/backups`?

Comment: @benett The approach with find is only able to cope with local copying unfortunately. You can not run find on a remote host. If your source or target accesses a remote host, then find can not easily be used.